# Python - Pandas - .str.contains filter for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently using the .str.contains function from the pandas module, to filter cells containing certain text.
I have now managed to get the filter to work for 1 columns, however after doing some research and testing i am unable to get this to filter 2 columns.

Example Input Data:

[image]

Syntax Example 1:

These syntaxes work on their own to produce the following output:

```
test1 = data[data["Date"].str.contains("Tue 02 Feb 2021")]
```

[image]

```
test2 = data[data["Agent"].str.contains("NaN", na=True, regex=False)]
```

[image]

Syntax Example 2

When trying to put these together using | this does not work, but does not return any errors

```
test3 = data[data["Agent"].str.contains("NaN", na=True, regex=False) | data["Date"].str.contains("Tue 02 Feb 2021")]
```

Comment: try with this test3 = data[(data["Agent"].str.contains("NaN", na=True, regex=False)) | (data["Date"].str.contains("Tue 02 Feb 2021"))]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you are wanting to filter down your dataframe right? I think you would want `&` instead of `|` in that case

```
>>> test3 = data[data["Agent"].str.contains("NaN", na=True, regex=False) & data["Date"].str.contains("Tue 02 Feb 2021")]
>>> print(test3)
  Agent Description             Date
2  None     example  Tue 02 Feb 2021
4  None     example  Tue 02 Feb 2021
>>>
```

Comment: Perfect - this is what i was trying to figure out, and this has worked. Thanks a lot - sorry if the terms in my explanation were a bit off, still learning the terms as i'm going along :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the conditionnal expression into parenthesis :

```py
data[(data["Agent"].str.contains("NaN", na=True, regex=False) | data["Date"].str.contains("Tue 02 Feb 2021"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test3 = data[np.logical_or(data["Agent"].str.contains("NaN", na=True, regex=False), data["Date"].str.contains("Tue 02 Feb 2021"))]
```

You can also enclose it in parentheses because the or (|) operator is overloaded for numpy arrays.